# Is combat affected by difficulty?

Tags: civilization-2

I haven't experimented much with difficulty levels, but I vaguely get the sense that winning combat in lower levels like Chieftain is much easier than higher levels. Is this true - does the difficulty level factor into the combat calculations? Or is it all an illusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

The [combat formula](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ2/strategy/combatguide) is quite complex, but it does not take difficulty level into account. However, there are two effects which might factor into this "illusion":

- **Barbarian attack strength** *is* affected by difficulty. Barbarian units are much weaker than their regular counterparts at lower difficulties. Above King though, they are *stronger*! Here's the full list of attack multipliers:

> - Chieftan        x0.25  the normal attack value
> - Warlord        x0.5
> - Prince        x0.75
> - King        x1
> - Emperor        x1.25
> - Deity        x1.50

- On lower difficulty levels, the AI develops much slower, which includes building ***city walls***. This improvement has a dramatic effect: it *triples* the defensive strength of garrisoned units. This means that, for example, a phalanx (1/2/1) will have a defensive strength of 6! You pretty much have to go for catapults (6/1/1), or veteran legions (4/2/1 x 1.5, or 6/3/1) to stand a fair chance.

One other thing which might be relevant is: advanced units often have special factors or abilities that novice players may not be aware of. On lower difficulty levels, it's much easier to gain a tech advantage to the AI, which means you're likely to have more advanced units.

- ***Hit Points*** and ***Firepower***: these two stats are often ignored by novice players, which is understandable since they are both 1 until quite late into the game, with units like *musketeer* (2 hp) and *cruiser* (2 fp). But they have a huge impact: hit points is self-explanatory and determines how long the unit stays in combat, and firepower is how much damage the unit deals per hit. You can imagine how much difference it makes when one of these numbers goes from 1 to 2. If it seems like your musketeers never die to your enemies' legions despite their attack being higher than your defense, or if your artillery seems to slice through enemies more than you'd expect, then these two stats are to blame.
- ***"Ignores city walls"***: this is a special ability that appears very late into the game: with aircraft, and the howitzers. When you first get the fighter, the stats seem miniscule: 4 attack 3 defense, but because they bypass city walls (and fortresses), they are effectively *3 times better* at attacking built-up cities, which is why the late game is dominated by bombers.